# Are there global asserts in C?

Tags: c, assert

Say I have a program where the value of an integer `i` should never be negative. Is there a way I can insert a global `assert(i>=0)` such that whenever `i` becomes negative an error is reported. This can be very useful while debugging. I don't want to put an assert everywhere the value of `i` is manipulated.

Comment: `assert()` won't be contained in the release version of your program, so don't worry about the efficiency issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Your debugger might have this sort of facility, though.  For instance, GDB has [watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to pick a point in the program's execution to keep checking that variable/assert.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just declare i as unsigned?

Comment: You can sing about the sign of an int, and then sign the song with your name. If the int is positive then it may become a global top hit. ;)

Comment: And an assert will? Cause you are sure you will test it with every possible input?

Comment: @George: An assert will **help** prevent erroneous code, by loudly exploding when the constraint is violated. It will not guarantee the correctness of the code unless every possible input is tested, true. Just changing `i` to unsigned prevents erroneous code only if the error was that the code needs positive values between `INT_MAX` and `UINT_MAX`. It doesn't detect errors at all -- in cases where the code erroneously produced a negative signed value you instead get a positive value that's wrong, and normally that's about as dangerous.